# Chrome 53 displaying wrong colours on external monitor on OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, google-chrome, multiple-monitors

Our company uses Macbook Pros as dev machines with external monitors.

Recently Chrome 53 started displaying the wrong colours in a PHP/Javascript web app when displayed on an external monitor.

The colour issue does not occur if Chrome is dragged to the internal MacBook Pro screen.

The colour issue does not occur in Safari, Opera or Firefox.

This is happening on 2 notebooks.
Does anyone have a hint as to the cause or potential solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a link to a problem where Chrome made the screen black on Windows 10 and thought it may be related.

The suggested solution was to disable hardware acceleration in Chrome Advanced settings.

I tried this and it worked - colours have returned to normal.

I still feel this is a Chrome defect, but at least the colours on the external monitor are distinguishable.